# Problem Statement : Merge Sub Array such that they don't have same elements consecutively

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

We have an interger array A of length N and two empty baskets.

The baskets are special because if any basket has two consecutive equal elements, then one of those elements magically disappear from that basket automatically.

You play a game using these baskets. In the game you need to place all elements of A sequentially from 0 to N-1 into either one of the baskets. The size of a basket is given by the number of elements of A contained in it.

Find the max possible sum of sizes of these two baskets.

```
public static int countDistinctPairs(int[] A) {
    ArrayList<Integer> basket1 = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> basket2 = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int num : A) {
        if (basket1.size() != 0 && basket1.get(basket1.size()-1) == num) {
            if (basket2.size() == 0 ||(basket2.size()!=0 && basket2.get(basket2.size()-1) !=num)) {
                basket2.add(num);
            }
        } else {
            basket1.add(num);
        }
    }

    return basket1.size() + basket2.size();
}
```

I wrote this code but majority test case failed.

Comment: whats the logic behind you writing the if else? That doesnt seem to be part of the requirement. It just says one of those elements disappear from basket automatically. Do they mean remove it entirely, or move to other basket?

Comment: @experiment unit 1998X We can remove them entirely.

Comment: if they want you to remove it entirely, then do you think that when you occasionally add it to second basket, it causes you to have a size larger than the "expected" answer so it fails the test case?

Comment: A couple of example arrays to think about: `1,1,2,3,2,2` and `1,1,2,3,1,1`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to subtract them when they magically disappear! In fact, you add to bucket one when sometimes you'll want to skip that add because it is the same as in bucket1. So if you skip both adds, a subtract has to happen! You can look at the remove function for arraylists.

Comment: can you please point out the code changes. Thanks.

Comment: Before you add to bucket 1, check your if statement again: ```
        if (basket1.size() != 0 && basket1.get(basket1.size()-1) == num) {```. If that is true, you know basket1 has the num on top. So you'll run basket1.remove on the last element at size-1 and skip the add (do the add in an else).